# How to send test results (CSV file) in Jmeter through Email after Test Run

Tags: jmeter

Please provide the solution for how to send test results (CSV file) in Jmeter through Email after Test Run.

How to schedule the test for particular time and send mail automatically

Awaiting for your response

Comment: I have created test plan with thread .under thread i have created transaction .i have added listener Summary report.Then i have add SMTP Sampler and i have configured with mail.

Answer (score 1):

1. Add the next line to *user.properties* file (located in the "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

   ```
   jmeter.save.saveservice.autoflush=true
   ```
2. Add [tearDown Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#tearDown_Thread_Group) to your [Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan)
3. Put [SMTP Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#SMTP_Sampler) under the tearDown Thread Group, configure SMTP server details, credentials, etc. and set it to send `testresult.csv` as the attachment. See [Load Testing Your Email Server: How to Send and Receive E-mails with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-your-email-server-how-send-and-receive-e-mails-jmeter) for more information and some example configuraiton.
4. Run your test in [command-line non-GUI mode](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) like:

   ```
   jmeter -n -t yourtest.jmx -l testresult.csv
   ```
5. That's it, JMeter will run your test and send results via email upon test completion.

Comment: thanks please provide me the steps how to run my test in command line non gui mode.